# How to connect Twilio autopilot to voice call with custom memory parameters

Tags: c#, twilio

I'm trying connect Twilio autopilot to voice call with custom data.  According to documentation there is Memory parameter where I can put custom data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Connect action="https://www.example.com/autopilot">
    <Autopilot Memory={"CarModel":"Diablo","CarMake":"Lamborghini","CarYear":"2019"}>UAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Autopilot>
  </Connect>
</Response>
```

But when I try to put it via strong types I receive a message "Sorry an error occurred."
Here is the method:

```
public VoiceResponse ConnectAutopilot(Guid requestId)
        {
            var response = new VoiceResponse();
             
            var autopilotUrl =
                $"https://channels.autopilot.twilio.com/v1/{ AccountSid}/{AutopilotName }/twilio-voice";
            var connect = new Connect
                          {
                              Action = new Uri(autopilotUrl)
                          };
            var pilot = new Autopilot { Name = AutopilotName};
            pilot.SetOption("Memory", new{requestId});
            pilot.SetOption("TargetTask", "greeting");
            connect.Append(pilot);
            response.Append(connect);
            response.Hangup();
            return response;
        }
```

Comment: Did you compare the TwiML response from your code vs. the working TwiML example from the documentation you posted? Example 3: Connect call to Autopilot and pass Inbound Context - https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/channels/voice#autopilot-twiml-noun

Comment: Thank you you were right issue was in this line pilot.SetOption("Memory", new{requestId});